# simplifying 6 mysql queries in 1 page

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a script that opens 6 MySQL queries in 1 php page. here's the script:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["name"]) || empty($_SESSION["name"])) {
        header("Location: http://www.google");
        die();
    } else {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "user";
        $password = "123";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
        $conn2 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
        $conn3 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
        $conn4 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
        $conn5 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
        $conn6 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

        if ($conn4->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn4->connect_error);
        }
        $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM tableT WHERE date(ftdate) = curdate()"; 
        $result4 = $conn4->query($sql4);
        $row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc();
        $conn4->close();
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");

        if ($result4->num_rows < 1) {
            if ($conn3->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn3->connect_error);
            }
            $date = date("Y-m-d");
            $sql3 = 'INSERT INTO tableT (`id`, `date`) VALUES (Null, "' . $date . '")';

            if ($conn3->query($sql3) === TRUE) {
                header("Location: http://google.com");
                die();
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql3 . "<br>" . $conn3->error;
            }
            $conn3->close();
        } Else {
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
            if ($conn2->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn2->connect_error);
            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE something = '0'";
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM tableP WHERE id=1"; 

            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            $conn->close();

            $result2 = $conn2->query($sql2);
            $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
            $conn2->close();


            if ($conn5->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn5->connect_error);
            }
            $month = date("m");
            $sql5 = "SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE month(date) = '" . $month . "' AND something = '1' ORDER BY fid"; 
            $result5 = $conn5->query($sql5);

            if ($result5->num_rows > 0) {
                $x = 1;
                $monthlyt = 0;

                $y = 0;
                $dailyt = 0;
                $day = date("Y-m-d");

                while($row5 = $result5->fetch_assoc()) { 
                    $monthlyt = $row5[ftotal] + $monthlyt;
                    $x = $x + 1;

                    $dbdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row5[fdate]));

                    if ($dbdate == $day) { 
                    $y = $y + 1;
                    $dailyt = $row5[total] + $dailyt;
                    }
                }
                $damount = ($y / $row2[something]) * 100;
                $dtotal = ($dailyt / $row2[some]) * 100;
                $mtotal = ($monthlyt / $row2[blah]) * 100;
            }
            $conn5->close();

            if ($conn6->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn6->connect_error);
            }

            $sql6 = 'UPDATE tableT SET something="' . $y . '", some="' . $blah. '" WHERE tdate="' . $day . '"'; 

            if ($conn6->query($sql6) === TRUE) {
                //done
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql6 . "<br>" . $conn6->error;
            }
            $conn6->close();
        }
    }
```

this page loads a dashboard showing a few different tables and some average response time calculations.

it was working previously, but I got an error saying "website redirected you too many times" Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS from chrome today.

So i'm thinking, is there a way I can simplify this? or would this lead to errors?

Comment: you don't need to have that many connections, just reuse `$conn`, its enough

Comment: That error has nothing to do with database connections, so you might want to look elsewhere for that.

Comment: ok, so does that mean I don't need so many die if connection failed statements as well?

Comment: any idea on what the error could be? coz the page is up and running again right now, but I'd like to have it running at all times as it's time sensitive.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: If you need more than one connection, use connection pooling. Don't do it this way. Each connection to the server is an expensive resource, so once you've got a connection use it as much as you can and discard it only if you have to.

Comment: `header("Location...` will do a redirect. I assume you entered the url of your page there. So if you don't have a session, you redirect to a page that redirects to that page if you don't have a session, that redirects to a page that redirects to that page if you don't have a session, that redirects to a page that redirects to that page if you don't have a session, that redirects to a page that redirects to that page if you don't have a session, that redirects to a page that redirects to that page if you don't have a session, that redirects to a page that redirects to that page if you don't hav

Comment: what do you mean by connection pooling? as per my code, did I fully utilize the connection?

Comment: i understand what you mean from the header"location" but the page it's redirecting to is the login page and i don't check for sessions there.